# Installing python pymssql

Tags: python

I am trying to install pymssql with no luck:

```
pip install pymssql
Downloading/unpacking pymssql
  Downloading pymssql-2.0.1.tar.bz2 (1.9MB): 1.9MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pymssql/setup.py) egg_info for package pymssql
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('32bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('debian', '7.3', '')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.3.4')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']

    warning: no files found matching 'win32/freetds.zip'
Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('32bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('debian', '7.3', '')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.3.4')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    building '_mssql' extension
    i486-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
    _mssql.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
     #include "pyconfig.h"
                          ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'i486-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptoolº tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8cJl01-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'

setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('32bit', 'ELF')

setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('debian', '7.3', '')

setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.3.4')

setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS

setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']

setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']

running install

running build

running build_ext

building '_mssql' extension

creating build

creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7

i486-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB

_mssql.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

 #include "pyconfig.h"

                      ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'i486-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptoolº tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8cJl01-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pymssql
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Any ideea why?

Answer (score 3):

It could be that you are missing the `python-dev` package

Comment: Also, I found that `freetds-dev' is required too